# Moving installed program different directory

Tags: command-line, filesystem, directory, preferences

I'm fairly new to linux (only because the programs I typically use are not supported by it, such as AutoCAD, SolidWorks, Visual Studio, etc..) but I'm a big fan of old school DOS (when it was actually DOS).

I have plenty of questions, but I'm trying to do my homework. However, I sometimes get many different answers (which is nice that there's so many ways to go about things, but difficult starting out!). I'm looking for 'best practices' and secure "correct" ways of doing things.

I installed sublime text editor, but it installed in the downloads directory, and I want it in `/usr/local/bin` (I think that's the standard place to put things for users..). I did a mv command on the directory, but if it's anything like windows (bleh) then it's going to screw things up. Is there anything else I need to do? Is there a "registry" database or something that tells linux (besides the `$PATH` variable) where to find it, and how to run it via command line?

Comment: there are advantages to being within /home.  assuming you have /home is a different partition; upgrading etc, even changing distro can format the / and leave your /home partition alone; hence apps (esp. data) can  make some sense. Yes Ubuntu is good & tries to avoid formatting, but other distros are not as helpful. Nope no registry blah.

Comment: Linux terminal verbose and commands are more plentiful than the older DOS. I am a DOS disciple, too! To run a command from command-line without refer complete path, it must be configured in  $PATH variable. You can do it on ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile. I prefer install additional programs in `/opt` folder, but `/usr/bin`or `/usr/local/bin`are widely used, too.

Comment: Linux programs are not bound to registry lines as Windows does. Usually some configurations are stored at ~/.config folder or any other, depending on the software you are dealing with. Specifically to Sublime Text, you should look at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/

Comment: You will note that rather than manual installation of the Sublime text editor the home page has some details of a repository to enable easy installation and any subsequent upgrades: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/linux_repositories.html

Comment: Ok, thank you all! I'm still busy learning the bazillion things that are available at linux command line (and love it, but wow!). I haven't gotten to the ability to partition and install root on a different partition yet. I've gotten lazy over the years. I have plenty of questions, but I'm going to do more reading and video watching. Maybe in a month or two, I won't have those questions anymore. ;) (Thank you!)